# Is there a significant overhead in calling `np.asarray' on a NumPy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am quite new to the Python world, so please excuse my dumb question.

In a number of circumstances, I implement a functions that works on array-like numerical inputs, and it is usually advantageous to make use of NumPy utilities for basic operations on the sequences.  To this end, I would write something like this:

```
import numpy as np

def f(x):
    if not isinstance(x, np.ndarray):
        x = np.asarray(x)
    # and from now on we know that x is a NumPy array, with all standard methods
```

(Note that I don't want to rely on the caller to always pass NumPy arrays.)

I was wondering what would be the additional overhead if simplified the code by removing the `if`?  I.e., having something like

```
def f(x):
    x = np.asarray(x)
    # and from now on we know that x is a NumPy array, with all standard methods
```

Basically, the difference between two cases is that second code is more compact, but will unnecessarily call `np.asarray` even if `x` is already a NumPy array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short answer:** Since you are checking with `isinstance()`, you may use `numpy.asanyarray()` which will pass through any `ndarray` and its subclasses without overhead.

According to the docs for [numpy.asarray()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html), when the input is already an `ndarray` type, there is no overhead when the input is already an array: no copying happens, they "pass through". Although, it is worth noting that a subclass of `ndarray` does not pass through.

Since in your original code you are using `isinstance(x, numpy.ndarray)`, you most likely will want [`numpy.asanyarray()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.asanyarray.html#numpy.asanyarray) which passes though the subclasses of `ndarray` also, which would be more efficient for your use case. (Because `isinstance()` returns true for subclasses as well)

> Returns:   out : ndarray Array interpretation of a. No copy is
> performed if the input is already an ndarray with matching dtype and
> order. If a is a subclass of ndarray, a base class ndarray is
> returned.

This example from the docs (plus my own comments) explains the differences and why `asanyarray()` is better for your use case:

```
>>> issubclass(np.recarray, np.ndarray)
True   # This is to show that recarray is a subclass of ndarray
>>> a = np.array([(1.0, 2), (3.0, 4)], dtype='f4,i4').view(np.recarray)
>>> np.asarray(a) is a
False  # Here a copy happens which is an overhead you do not want,
       # because the input type recarray is only a subclass of ndarray
>>> np.asanyarray(a) is a
True   # Here no copying happens, your subclass of ndarray passes through.
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code, `np.asarray` does:

```
array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
```

`np.asanyarray` does

```
array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order, subok=True)
```

defaults for `np.array` are:

```
array(object, dtype=None, copy=True, order='K', subok=False, ndmin=0)
```